# C# Securely delete variable from memory

Tags: c#, security, memory

I'm making a security related program and I want to be sure that I'm doing this the right way. When someone logs in with a password, a secret key is decrypted and stored in a variable. When they log out, I want the data in memory for that secret key to be completely erased, not just marked as deleted. I'm currently doing the following:

```
public void Logout()
{
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) Math.Round((double) (_phraseHash.Count()))];
        rngCsp.GetBytes(data);
        int randomNum = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
        _phraseHash = randomNum.ToString();
    }
    LoggedIn = false;
    _phraseHash = null;
}
```

What I want to know is if this will be sufficient to completely erase the secret key (_phraseHash) from the system.

Also is this even necessary? I don't actually know much about how data in memory is deleted, I just assumed it would be somewhat similar to how hard drives work where bytes are just marked deleted and rewritten when something else needs the space.

Comment: Why  don't you use [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) to store password?

Comment: Normally the approved method of destroying data is to alternately overwrite data 5 times with all 0's then all 1's.

Comment: setting value to null won't really help, because data will still be in the memory, the pointer will just stop 'pointing' to it. If you want to clear the memory, you should rather overwrite it a few times with random data and then force the Garbage Collector to act (`GC.Collect()`) - the GC won't act immediately after setting value to null.

Comment: @jdweng: You can'r rely on the memory address that the string is on an any time, so 'overwriting' in __n times__ may well write to __n different__ locations and __never__ hit the orginal password.

Comment: Where did I ever say anything about memory address?  It would help to make the data static so it is always at the same memory address and not on the execution stack where the location can change.

Comment: What makes you think a static variable is not moved around during execution? You would need to pin it in memory explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

I think you might be interested in [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> An instance of the System.String class is both immutable and, when no longer needed, cannot be programmatically scheduled for garbage collection; that is, the instance is read-only after it is created, and it is not possible to predict when the instance will be deleted from computer memory. Because System.String instances are immutable, operations that appear to modify an existing instance actually create a copy of it to manipulate. Consequently, if a String object contains sensitive information such as a password, credit card number, or personal data, there is a risk the information could be revealed after it is used because your application cannot delete the data from computer memory.
>
> A SecureString object is similar to a String object in that it has a
>   text value. However, the value of a SecureString object is pinned in
>   memory, may use a protection mechanism, such as encryption, provided
>   by the underlying operating system, can be modified until your
>   application marks it as read-only, and can be deleted from computer
>   memory either by your application calling the Dispose method or by the
>   .NET Framework garbage collector.

Comment: This is an interesting read, too: [How secure is SecureString?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#HowSecure)

Comment: Thank you both, I think this answers my question. I will mark it as such once I've implemented it successfully.

Comment: Ok so I tried to use SecureString but it's not compatible with string so in order to use it I would have to replace every string in my encryption class and add support for securestring -> byte array. Any ideas?

Comment: Only secret key I suppose. And you can use AppendChar(char c) for SecureString class.

Comment: Indeed. _A SecureString object should never be constructed from a String, because the sensitive data is already subject to the memory persistence consequences of the immutable String class. The best way to construct a SecureString object is from a character-at-a-time unmanaged source, such as the Console.ReadKey method._

Comment: What if I then need to get the plain text out of the secure string to send to an API call? How do I deal with that string object being in memory?

Comment: Well, you can copy it to unmanaged memory Marshal.SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode, send it as a byte array and 
 then Zero it (Marshal.ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode) along with byte array used.

Answer (score 0):

MS documentation on Secure String --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#HowSecure

Following should tell you that SecureString should not be used for storing password if the security is your paramount concern.

> Even if the SecureString implementation is able to take advantage of
>   encryption, the plain text assigned to the SecureString instance may
>   be exposed at various times:
>
> Because Windows doesn't offer a secure string implementation at the
>   operating system level, the .NET Framework still has to convert the
>   secure string value to its plain text representation in order to use
>   it.
>
> Whenever the value of the secure string is modified by methods such as
>   AppendChar or RemoveAt, it must be decrypted (that is, converted back
>   to plain text), modified, and then encrypted again.
>
> If the secure string is used in an interop call, it must be converted
>   to an ANSI string, a Unicode string, or a binary string (BSTR). For
>   more information, see the SecureString and interop section.
>
> The time interval for which the SecureString instance's value is
>   exposed is merely shortened in comparison to the String class.
>
> Storage versus usage More generally, the SecureString class defines a
>   storage mechanism for string values that should be protected or kept
>   confidential. However, outside of the .NET Framework itself, no usage
>   mechanism supports SecureString. This means that the secure string
>   must be converted to a usable form (typically a clear text form) that
>   can be recognized by its target, and that decryption and conversion
>   must occur in user space.
>
> Overall, SecureString is more secure than String because it limits the
>   exposure of sensitive string data. However, those strings may still be
>   exposed to any process or operation that has access to raw memory,
>   such as a malicious process running on the host computer, a process
>   dump, or a user-viewable swap file. **Instead of using SecureString to
>   protect passwords, the recommended alternative is to use an opaque
>   handle to credentials that are stored outside of the process.**